# Push To Mongoose Subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hello I am creating a series of groupings describing the roles certain users are taking within the context of helping a client. The object in the Prospect model is called caseworkers.  In caseworkers is a series of arrays for the different types of roles done. The equation is to allow the user to push his info as a subdocument called CaseWorker.  Basically creating an object with 6 arrays that users can push to. Ive tried a few things and settled on Subdocuments. Any help would be awesome.

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const CaseWorker = require("./CaseWorker");

const ProspectSchema = mongoose.Schema({


  caseWorkers: {
    originators: [CaseWorker.schema],
    loanProcessors: [CaseWorker.schema],
    documentProcessors: [CaseWorker.schema],
    upsells: [CaseWorker.schema],
    primaryReso: [CaseWorker.schema],
    taxPreparers: [CaseWorker.schema],
    secondaryReso: [CaseWorker.schema],
  }
module.exports = mongoose.model("prospect", ProspectSchema);
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CaseWorkerSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  role: { type: String },
  resoCred1: { type: String },
  resoCred2: { type: String },
  reminders: [
    {
      _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      userReminded: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
      reminderDate: { type: Date },
      reminderDueDate: { type: Date },
      status: { type: String },
      daysTilDue: { type: Number },
      id: { type: String },
      text: { type: String },
      clientId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Prospect" },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("caseWorker", CaseWorkerSchema);
```

```
router.put("/:_id/caseWorkers/loanProcessors", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const prospect = await Prospect.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, {
    "$push": {
      "loanProcessors": {
        "caseWorker": {
          "name": req.body.name,
          "email": req.body.email,
          "role": req.body.role,
          "resoCred1": req.body.resoCred1,
          "resoCred2": req.body.resoCred2,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  res.json(prospect);
  console.log(prospect);
});
```

Comment: so what is your actual issue? or just asking for a probable better options?

Comment: it doesnt work. as in the push doesnt expand the array, in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach when updating the document you put `caseWorker` under `loanProcessors` but it's declared in the schema the other way around.

To update a nested object you have to use the dot notation to reference the field.

Don't forget to put the object key that represent the field as a string like this `"caseWorkers.loanProcessors"`, because `caseWorkers.loanProcessors` is an invalid object key in javascript

```
    "$push": {
      "caseWorkers.loanProcessors": {
        "name": req.body.name,
        "email": req.body.email,
        "role": req.body.role,
        "resoCred1": req.body.resoCred1,
        "resoCred2": req.body.resoCred2,
      },
    },
```

Comment: i believe either with `quotes` or without, both should work, otherwise if you have numerical character as the first character of the field name, then you need to use quotes.

Comment: @KarlL you can try it out in your browser javascript console. `{ a.b: 0 }` is invalid javascript syntax. `a.b` is not a valid identifier. Object keys has the same restriction as declaring variables. You can not do `const a.b = 0`. If it's not a valid identifier you have to put it between quotes to make it a valid object key.